# Search in multidimensional Stdclass PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I want to search in PHP within a specific object. For instance **[module] => play** in a StdClass object, how can I search for values within the class itself?

Below you can find the whole array:

```
            [flow] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [data] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [action] => start
                        )

                    [module] => record_call
                    [children] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [data] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7696364e90822fdcba4feee30574a7e2
                                            [endless_playback] => 
                                            [terminators] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [module] => play
                                    [children] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => stdClass Object
….
```

I want to get the output like:

```
                                    [data] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7696364e90822fdcba4feee30574a7e2
                                            [endless_playback] => 
                                            [terminators] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [module] => play
                                    [children] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_] => stdClass Object
….
```

Can someone help me with that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does your data have to be in the form of `stdClass` objects? If you're receiving your data via `json_decode()`, you can pass `true` in as a second parameter to receive an associative array instead, in which case you can perform a recursive array search easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of simpler options here.

The first is if you're receiving this data via a `json_decode()` call, add `true` as a second parameter:

```
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
```

The second is to convert this to a simple associative array structure by taking advantage of the above and the use of `json_encode()`:

```
$decoded = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
```

With your simple array structure, it's now possible to recursively traverse the array to find the matching key/value pair desired:

```
function findModule($data, $module_name) {
    if(!is_array($data)) return null;

    if(array_key_exists('module', $data)) {
        if($data['module'] === $module_name) {
            return $data;
        }
    }

    foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
        $result = findModule($val, $module_name);
        if(!is_null($result)) {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

// Will either return the array of array('data'=>..., 'module'=>'play', 'children': ...) or null if no matching module found.
$module = findModule($decoded, 'play');
```